# Fantasy story - young boy in a house in a swamp

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember a fantasy story I read with my children about 10-12 years ago and it was for children aged 8-13, I think.

We read it around the same time that the *Wind on Fire* trilogy came out so I may have mixed up bits but what I remember was a young boy on his own in a big house surrounded by swamp (?) and there were creatures in the swamp and I think they besieged the house when night fell. He manages to survive the night and escape but that's all I remember.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it one of the *Septimus Heap* books?

Comment: Possibly one of the short stories related to Lloyd Alexander's _Prydain Chronicles_?  Excuse me while I hunt around... hope I didn't give it away.

Comment: @randal'thor I don't think so, but I'll check - thanks for the suggestion